# How do I make a clickable terminal link that runs a function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I am using [ansi-escapes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-escapes) to make the link.
How would I make it run a function when the link is clicked? I'm okay with making it run a terminal command. And if so is there some sort of URI that I can use to run a terminal command? I am using Windows Terminal, however I would like it to work for other terminals as well.

Comment: Without capturing the terminal mouse and [mouse clicks](https://github.com/cronvel/terminal-kit/blob/HEAD/doc/high-level.md#ref.grabInput), maybe setup a koa/fastify/express server in your app to handle the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a link with a file:/// uri to a batch file, Windows Terminal will run it, because [it simply executes `open ${url}`](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/src/cascadia/TerminalApp/TerminalPage.cpp#L2413). From that batch file you can then run something like `node terminalCallback.js`.
The only [allowed uri protocols](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/src/cascadia/TerminalApp/TerminalPage.cpp#L2454) are:

1. http(s)
2. file